# Load event object by id

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

This is regarding jquery FullCalendar.

I want to access an event object loaded into the calendar by its id.  So someone clicks, I trap it and get the id of an event within the calendar and I wish to load get that particular eventObject.

I think this should be simple, but I can't find a way to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found it. clientEvents(filter)

http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/clientEvents/

Comment: When I try to run this function:

var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('clientEvents', event_id);

calendar returns a object with every event in the calendar. Why? :S